# How to show different popups on click and on mouseover?

Tags: popup, openlayers

The `SelectFeature` method in `Control` class provides a way of adding and removing popups on the Vector layer by listening to events `featureselected` and `featureunselected` respectively. Below shows a sample code that I obtained from [an example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/light-basic.html) in the openlayers website:

```js
// create the layer with listeners to create and destroy popups
var vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Points",{
 eventListeners:{
  'featureselected':function(evt){
   var feature = evt.feature;
   var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("popup",
    OpenLayers.LonLat.fromString(feature.geometry.toShortString()),
    null,
    "<div style='font-size:.8em'>Feature: " + feature.id +"<br>Foo: </div>",
    null,
    true
   );
   feature.popup = popup;
   map.addPopup(popup);
  },
  'featureunselected':function(evt){
   var feature = evt.feature;
   map.removePopup(feature.popup);
   feature.popup.destroy();
   feature.popup = null;
  }
 }
});

vector.addFeatures(features);

// create the select feature control
var selector = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vector,{
 hover:true, # this line
 autoActivate:true
});
```

The code above will allow a popup to be shown upon mouseover on the Geometry object (icon or marker on the map). If the line `hover:true` is removed, the popup will be shown only upon a mouse click on the Geometry object.

What I want, is to be able to display one type of popup (example, an image plus a title) upon mouseover and another type (example, detailed description) upon a mouse click. I am not sure how this could be done. Some help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I hope you can find solution from here: http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/highlight-feature.html

Comment: @user1702401, thanks for the tip. I notice that the example uses new event listeners available only in version 2.13. Can't wait for the stable release :)

Comment: If you mean "beforefeaturehighlighted", "featurehighlighted" and "featureunhighlighted" events, then those have existed for long time (at least since 2.11). Tested this example with 2.12 and works fine.

Comment: @user1702401, yes, you are right. I didn't manage to find it the first time and thought it is a new feature. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, there another way, it's rather hack than correct usage of API, but seems to work. You can overwrite over and out callbacks.

```
var selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer, {

    callbacks: {
        over: function(feat) {
            console.log('Show popup type 1');
        },
        out: function(feat) {
            console.log('Hide popup type 1');
        }
    },

    eventListeners: {
        featurehighlighted: function(feat) {
            console.log('Show popup type 2');
        },
        featureunhighlighted: function(feat) {
            console.log('Hide popup type 2');
        }
    }    
});
```

Here's working example: http://jsfiddle.net/eW8DV/1/

Take a look on select control's source to understand details.

Comment: I guess `beforefeaturehighlighted` would be just fine too. Thanks for showing me the hack :)